# PrimeNg change p-column width with template

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I get following error when trying to set dynamic column width
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{width: '180px', 'text-align': 'center'}'

```js
  <p-dataTable [value]="employees">
      <p-header>Employee List</p-header>
      <p-column *ngFor="let userColumn of userColumns" 
        [field]="userColumn.field"          [header]="userColumn.title" 
        [sortable]="userColumn.sort" [style]="userColumn.myStyle">
        </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

userColumns defined as

```js
 this.userColumns = [
    { 
      'field': 'userId', 
      'title': 'User Id',
      'sort': 'true',
      'template': '',
      'myStyle' : ''
    },
    { 'field': 'jobTitleName', 'title': 'Job title', 'sort': 'true','myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'lastName',  'title': 'Last name','sort': 'true', 'myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'preferredFullName',  'title': 'First name','sort': 'true', 'myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'dateOfJoining',  'title': 'Date of Joining','sort': 'true',
      'myStyle': '{width: \'180px\', \'text-align\': \'center\'}'
    }
```

Comment: If i define style inline there are no issues

Comment: are you looking to add styles to the data?

Comment: i want to provide different width to different columns in my table and through externally defined userColumns definition.

Comment: I see this issue discussed here, don't understand answer though https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/584

Comment: have you find any solution

Comment: "myStyle" is being treated as an string instead of object. If you fix the structure then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the definition of your styling and add a single quote around "width"
like this:

```
 this.userColumns = [
    { 
      'field': 'userId', 
      'title': 'User Id',
      'sort': 'true',
      'template': '',
      'myStyle' : ''
    },
    { 'field': 'jobTitleName', 'title': 'Job title', 'sort': 'true','myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'lastName',  'title': 'Last name','sort': 'true', 'myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'preferredFullName',  'title': 'First name','sort': 'true', 'myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'dateOfJoining',  'title': 'Date of Joining','sort': 'true',
      'myStyle': '{\'width\': \'180px\', \'text-align\': \'center\'}'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to define myStyle as Object rather than string.
Otherwise even if you don't get differ error but width will not be set.

```js
 this.userColumns = [
    { 
      'field': 'userId', 
      'title': 'User Id',
      'sort': 'true',
      'template': '',
       myStyle : ''
    },
    { 'field': 'jobTitleName', 'title': 'Job title', 'sort': 'true','myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'lastName',  'title': 'Last name','sort': 'true', 'myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'preferredFullName',  'title': 'First name','sort': 'true', 'myStyle': ''},
    { 'field': 'dateOfJoining',  'title': 'Date of Joining','sort': 'true',
      myStyle: {width: '180px', 'text-align': 'center'}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In primeng 12 they **removed colgroup template** so if you are using **colgroup** over the application need to remove because custom width is not working for column if you are using scrollable check migration guide.

link:https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide

solution:
you need to add same width for both tags **<th [style]="'width':'100px'"> and <td [style]="'width':'100px'">**
if you are using dynamic columns then add one more property width like below

**[{ header: "Name", field: "name", width: '100px' }] // column object array object**

```
<p-table [value]="data" [columns]="ColumnObjectArray">   
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns; let idx=index;" class="" 
                           [style]="'width':col.width">{{col.header}}</th>
               </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns">
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [style]="'width':col.width">
                       {{data[col.field]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**try this one you will definitely get the responsive width to table and also you will get the custom column and header width**
hope this will work for you